# React-bootstrap button with icon

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I can add a button with text in react-bootstrap using code like

```
        <Button
          className={styles.feedbackButtonRating}
          variant={this.state.liked ? 'success' : 'light'}
          onClick={this.handleOnLikeClick}
        >
          {FEEDBACK_LIKE_BUTTON_TEXT}
        </Button>
```

Is there a way to replace `{FEEDBACK_LIKE_BUTTON_TEXT}` text with a thumb up icon?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can try out using this npm package [react-icons](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-icons)

```
import { FaThumbsUp } from 'react-icons/fa';

<Button>
    <FaThumbsUp />
</Button>
```

Comment: I'm sure there's more than one right answer but this was quick and easy for me

Answer (score 2):

You can use font awesome library (npm-pakage) for reactjs.

Link : [Font-awesome for reactjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@fortawesome/react-fontawesome)

USE -

```
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";

<FontAwesomeIcon icon="signal" />
<FontAwesomeIcon icon="globe" />
```

Comment: Does this put the icon in a button?

Answer (score 0):

**For others that is looking for an alternative:**

You can install this: https://fontawesome.com/v5/docs/web/use-with/react

Then:

```
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome'
import { faPlus } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'

<Button>
 <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faPlus} />
</Button>
```